# Cake Running Nunit 3 using DotNetCoreTest Is Failing

Tags: nunit-3.0, cakebuild

```
Task("Nunit")
.Does(() => {
    DotNetCoreTest("D:\Workspace\Proj14\test\test\WebAutomation\NUnit\UserManageLMTWS.cs", );
    });
```

Currently have by build.cake defining the task as such as listed in the https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/8191BBC4 example. I don't have any settings, as I guess I'm building into Debug instead of Release, but I am getting the following errors when running the task:

```
Error: Bootstrapping failed for 'D:/Workspace/Proj14/test/test/Nunit'.
Nunit, line #0: Could not find script 'D:/Workspace/Proj14/test/test/Nunit'.
```

Do I need to pass NUnit into the DotNetCoreTest method somehow?

Answer (score 3):

[DotNetCoreTest](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/8191BBC4) is meant to test projects and not individual files.

So you specify either the `<PROJECT> | <SOLUTION> | <DIRECTORY>` file i.e.

- `DotNetCoreTest("./test/Project.Tests/", settings);`
- `DotNetCoreTest("./test/My.sln", settings);`
- `DotNetCoreTest("./test/Project.Tests/Project.Tests.csproj", settings);`

[DotNetCoreTest](https://cakebuild.net/api/Cake.Common.Tools.DotNetCore/DotNetCoreAliases/8191BBC4) calls to the .NET SDK CLI command [dotnet test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002677).

The error you're receiving though is because the path to the specified script is wrong / doesn't exist. There's no file called `D:/Workspace/Proj14/test/test/Nunit` which is why error message says `Could not find script 'D:/Workspace/Proj14/test/test/Nunit'`

Comment: Is there a solution to run individual Nunit .cs files from cakebuild then? My solution is 5 projects all filled with NUnit3 and Specflow tests, and I'd like to call certain tests with certain environment variables separately.

Comment: You can categorize tests, and then execute only those with certain categories, here's an blog post that describes that https://dotnetthoughts.net/running-a-specific-test-with-dotnet-core-and-nunit/